Pan and zoom help needed
I just started my journey to learn coding and doing it on the iPad with Swift playground.
I have an audio waveform to which I apply zoom and pan gestures. I’m having a bit of trouble. When I zoom in and pan all the way to the end of the waveform, if I try zooming out, the waveform tends to pan instead, and it disappears. Instead of the end of the waveform being attached to the background lines, I can see it moving. Could you also help implement a way to zoom between my finger?
Here is a YouTube of the issue https://youtu.be/RrP39Fv-_oc?si=sca_ys0vOnihLFGs and here is the code:
import SwiftUI

struct WaveformView: View {
    @Binding var waveform: [Float]
    @State private var zoomFactor: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State private var lastZoomFactor: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State private var offset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var lastOffset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var selectionStart: CGFloat = 0.0
    @State private var selectionEnd: CGFloat = 1.0

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.gray.opacity(0.3).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Canvas { context, size in
                        let middleY = size.height / 2
                        let maxAmplitude = size.height / 3 - 1
                        var path = Path()
                        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: middleY))
                        var previousPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: middleY)
                        for (index, sample) in waveform.enumerated() {
                            let x = (size.width * CGFloat(index) / CGFloat(waveform.count)) * zoomFactor - offset.width
                            let amplitude = max(min(CGFloat(sample) * maxAmplitude, maxAmplitude), -maxAmplitude)
                            let point = CGPoint(x: x, y: middleY - amplitude)
                            let controlPoint1 = CGPoint(x: (previousPoint.x + point.x) / 2, y: previousPoint.y)
                            let controlPoint2 = CGPoint(x: (previousPoint.x + point.x) / 2, y: point.y)
                            path.addCurve(to: point, control1: controlPoint1, control2: controlPoint2)
                            previousPoint = point
                        }
                        context.stroke(path, with: .color(.blue), lineWidth: 1)
                        
                        // Playhead line
                      
                    }
                    
                    // Selection overlay and handles
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.blue.opacity(0.3)) // Selection overlay color
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width * (selectionEnd - selectionStart), height: geometry.size.height)
                        .offset(x: geometry.size.width * selectionStart, y: 0)
                    
                    Circle() // Start handle
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                        .offset(x: geometry.size.width * selectionStart - 15, y: geometry.size.height / 2 - 15)
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture()
                                .onChanged { value in
                                    selectionStart = min(max(0, value.location.x / geometry.size.width), selectionEnd)
                                }
                        )
                    
                    Circle() // End handle
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                        .offset(x: geometry.size.width * selectionEnd - 15, y: geometry.size.height / 2 - 15)
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture()
                                .onChanged { value in
                                    selectionEnd = max(min(1, value.location.x / geometry.size.width), selectionStart)
                                }
                        )
                }
                .gesture(
                    SimultaneousGesture(
                        MagnificationGesture().onChanged { value in
                            let newZoomFactor = lastZoomFactor * value
                            self.zoomFactor = max(1.0, newZoomFactor)
                        }.onEnded { value in
                            if abs(self.zoomFactor - 1.0) < 0.05 {
                                self.zoomFactor = 1.0
                                self.offset = .zero
                                self.lastOffset = .zero
                            } else {
                                self.lastZoomFactor = self.zoomFactor
                                let adjustmentFactor = self.zoomFactor / self.lastZoomFactor
                                self.offset.width *= adjustmentFactor
                                self.lastOffset = self.offset
                            }
                        },
                        DragGesture().onChanged { value in
                            let proposedOffset = lastOffset.width - value.translation.width
                            let maxOffset = max((geometry.size.width * zoomFactor) - geometry.size.width, 0)
                            self.offset.width = min(max(proposedOffset, 0), maxOffset)
                        }.onEnded { value in
                            self.lastOffset = self.offset
                        }
                    )
                )
                .onChange(of: waveform) { _ in
                    resetSelection()
                    resetZoomAndOffset()
                }
                .gesture(TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded {
                    resetSelection()
                    resetZoomAndOffset()
                })
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func resetSelection() {
        selectionStart = 0.0
        selectionEnd = 1.0
    }
    
    private func resetZoomAndOffset() {
        zoomFactor = 1.0
        lastZoomFactor = 1.0
        offset = .zero
        lastOffset = .zero
    }
}

I zoom in, pan to the end of waveform, then try to zoom out.
Waveform detaches from background frame, pans instead of zooming out.
